# Clearing offset numbers

Tags: g-code, okuma

Is it better to clear RCompOffset and ToolLengthOffset with `G40` and `G53` respectively or is it better to clear them with `G42D0` and `G54H0`?

Would `G41D0` clear an LComp too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AppFzx,
G40 and G53 are the proper codes for removing respectively the radius compensation and the length compensation. Also, there is G56 for removing the length compensation: the difference between G53 and G56 is that G56 reset the tool offset number to none while G53 leaves it set.
Let me know if you need more information.

Regards,
Germano Zerbini
Application Engineer
Okuma America Corp.